# Responsive images in table using bootsrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have

```
----------------
     header
----------------
| t1 | t2 | t3 |
----------------
| i1 | i2 | i3 |
```

I need (via bootstrap, or direct css) the bottom images to be "responsive" (resize after the content width)

Here is my code (Plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/z0ojRuzClOlcZ9B0wUHn?p=preview)).
I tried `width:100%;` on `td` and `img-responsive` on `img`, but it didn't work.

```html
  <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.0.5" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.0.5" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <table style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan=3 class="text-center">My Pics</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="text-center">Trees</th>
        <th class="text-center">Cats</th>
        <th class="text-center">Bulding</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="width:100%;" class="text-center"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://unsplash.it/164/90"/></td>
        <td style="width:100%;" class="text-center"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://unsplash.it/164/91"/></td>
        <td style="width:100%;" class="text-center"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://unsplash.it/164/92"/></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the `style="width:100%;"` off of the `td`s and put it on the images themselves.  The table cells will size themselves automatically.

Check out new plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/kywXQv6C1c2rr2Xg0016?p=preview)

Answer (score 5):

`img-responsive` has changed to `img-fluid` so maybe try that first (bootstrap class).